# Should you highlight a small mistake, or pretend it didn't happen?

Tags: professionalism

Yesterday I talked a recruiter about a job, and told them I'd send them my CV that night.

Slipped my mind last night, so I'm sending it now.

Should I attach a 'Sorry for the delay' message with the email, or just say 'As discussed yesterday, here's my CV'?

Comment: I downgraded your question, because there is no way to give a high quality answer to a low quality question.

Comment: It's a recruiter, they'll take your CV and they'll like it. If they got snippy about every candidate that ever sent something a day late, they'd never have any candidates and they'd never make any money.

Comment: Don't worry, most recruiters are equally unreliable, I've found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Should I attach a 'Sorry for the delay' message with the email, or
>   just say 'As discussed yesterday, here's my CV'?

I think you are over-thinking this one. It almost certainly doesn't matter to the recruiter if you sent it last night or this morning.

Just send your resume without any "Sorry" or "As discussed yesterday" apology.

And take care not to let promises made during the job search slip your mind next time. While forgetting this time probably isn't impactful, other mis-steps might prove to be costly.

Comment: 'And take care...' Yes, ultimately it's a measure of the power of your word.